# About the sentence structure "Do you see where the sign is?

Tags: grammar

This is from a textbook for ESL students.

> At the information desk, a lady asks, "Where is the restroom?"  A man says, "It's just behind you.  Do you see where the sign is?"

Is this sentence structure *"Do you see where the sign is?"* the same as, for example,

> "Do you know where the restroom is?"

If I take this sentence as a *relative clause*, does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Forming a question

Let's form a question.  We'll perform four basic steps.

1. First, let's start with a declarative clause:

   > *The restroom* is **here**.
2. Next, let's turn it into an interrogative clause.  We'll do this by putting the interrogative word *where* in, replacing *here*:

   > *The restroom* is **where**?
3. Next, we need to move the interrogative phrase containing *where* to the front.  In this example, that phrase is just the word *where* by itself:

   > [ **where** *the restroom* is ]
4. And finally, we'll make it into a main clause question using Subject-Auxiliary Inversion.  Our subject is *the restroom*, and our auxiliary is *is*, so we'll just switch those two around:

   > **Where** is *the restroom*?

And we're done!  Those are the basic steps.  They can be a little bit different for other sentences, and I've written up [some more examples over here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14137/english-grammar-wh-question-forms/14156#14156), but for this question we're going to ignore those details and move on.  We've got ourselves a question!

---

## Interrogative content clauses

Not every interrogative clause is an entire sentence by itself.  Sometimes we use an interrogative clause as part of a larger sentence.  When we do, we follow the same steps, except we don't perform Subject-Auxiliary Inversion.  Let's take a look:

1. We'll start with our interrogative clause from step 3 above:

   > [ **where** *the restroom* is ]
2. We can use this as part of a larger sentence as a content clause:

   > I don't know [ **where** *the restroom* is ] .
3. And that larger sentence can be a question, too:

   > Do you know [ **where** *the restroom* is ] ?
4. And we can use your other example the same way, because it has the same structure:

   > Do you see [ **where** *the sign* is ] ?

Okay, let's move on!

---

## Content clauses and relative clauses

Subordinate clauses can be relative, but not all of them are.  The name for a basic type of subordinate clause without any special function (relative or comparative) is "content clause", and that's the name I've used so far.

But you *could* use a clause like this as a relative if you wanted to.  For example:

> I went to the **school** [ **where** *the sign* is ] .

Here, "where the sign is" is a relative clause modifying the head noun "school".  But there's no such relationship in the other examples, so we have no reason to call them relative clauses.  That's why I used the term "content clause" instead earlier.

In short, your examples have the same structure as one other, but they're not relatives.  They're interrogative content clauses.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer of *where it is* is finished in the very first clause `it's just behind you`. The speaker further *instructs* that it's **the** place with some *sign*. I'm not sure whether it serves as a relative clause.

To answer your first question -whether the former structure is the same as the latter in your example, I'd say *it's not the same.* As I said, this is answered `just behind you`

The relative clause what I think could be something like -

> Where's the restroom ~ it's over there, the room with a *lady's sign*.

[image]