# What job should I have or What job I should have?

Tags: word-choice

I want to ask myself what kind of job I'm gonna do. I want to know which one should be ok:

1. What job should I have?
2. What job I should have?

Thanks,

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14156/3281. Here is a list of [auxiliary verbs you can find on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb): be (am, are, is, was, were, being, been), can, could, dare, do (does, did), have (has, had, having), may, might, must, need, ought, shall, should, will, would.

Comment: This is addressed at ["How it works?" vs. "How does it work?"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17778/how-it-works-vs-how-does-it-work). (1) is a question; (2) is a free relative clause which acts as a nominal; it is not a complete sentence, and it should not have a question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a direct question , then the first sentence is correct: What job should I have?".                                                                                   If it is an indirect question like,"I I want to ask myself what job I shoud have?",the second option is correct.                                                                        An indirect sentence the verb is in the affirmative. 
Another example: **direct question**= *"What did yoy make for dinner?"*
                **indirect question**= *Bob asked me what I had made for dinner.*

Answer (score 1):

The word order in English is usually subject - verb - object, with an auxiliary verb ("should") before the subject ("I") in questions: interrogative - auxiliary verb - subject - main verb - object. However, with "wh-fronting", you have an inversion of the word order. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a good site explaining that, and the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative#Syntax) is difficult to understand... Anyway, number 1 is correct.

I have a job.
Do I have a job?
Should I have a job?
What job should I have?