# At what time I should / should I come tomorrow?

Tags: questions, word-order, subject-auxiliary-inversion

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> 1. At what time **I should** come tomorrow?
> 2. At what time **should I** come tomorrow?

I'd like to know where I should put the word *should*.

Comment: While we can certainly tell you which is correct, it will help you more if you tell us which you think is correct and why and then we can explain whether you have the right idea or not.

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking which _question_ is correct? If so, you should probably put question marks at the end of each one.

Comment: A little punctuation goes a long way. . .Am I supposed to self-put dots there, commas, periods, or question marks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What job should I have or What job I should have?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26704/what-job-should-i-have-or-what-job-i-should-have)

Answer (score 3):

> At what time should I come tomorrow?

Is correct.

We can also ask:

> I should come at what time tomorrow?

But the first form is the most common.

Please see ["How it works?" vs. "How does it work?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17778/how-it-works-vs-how-does-it-work) for more information.