# How do I use the auxiliary "do" in questions?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs, subjects

Consider these two sentences:

> Who left the door open?

and

> Who do you want to speak to?

In the first question auxiliary *do* cannot normally be used, but in the latter question it can. Why is that so? What is it about the second sentence that requires auxiliary *do* that the first sentence doesn't have? Please include a few more examples of this pattern if possible.

Comment: Do you want more examples or what? Unclear what you're asking. Flagged.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Recommended reading: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14156/3281. (I think this question is a duplicate, but let's wait and see the OP's feedback first.) See also: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/3538/3281.

Comment: @Dmitry Can you please explain what you want to know in more detail? Are you wondering about the when to use *do* if *who* is the subject, or just about *do* in general?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I don't understand when I must use auxillary __do__, and when don't. BTW, why do you substitute my __bit__ to few?

Comment: @Dmitry Good question. In general (there are a few exceptions), *bit* is for uncountable nouns and *few* is for countable ones. You can count the number of examples, so I changed it to *few*. For example, you would say *a bit of* *money*, *running*, *water*, or *glue*.

Comment: To add one more link, this one gives you more information on when using the auxiliary is possible in the first: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13469/auxilliary-do-with-the-subject-in-questions 
@Dmitry Fucintv, after you read that please edit your question to explain exactly what it is that you do not understand.

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't know the answer to this one, but I can't see why it's "Unclear". It is of course possible to ask *"Who did leave the door open?"* in certain contexts, but I think probably the reason why ***do*** doesn't normally work there is something to do with whether ***who*** is the *subject* or the *object* in syntactic terms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are called [subject questions (as your first example) and object questions (as your second)](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/question-forms-subjectobject-questions). Here we are talking about "do", so this is present simple and past simple tense. Let us take one example:

```
Paul wants to speak to him.
```

1) If we want to know who "him" is, "him" is the object and the question we will ask is an **object question**. There will be an auxiliary verb, which will come between the question word and the subject:

```
Who does Paul want to speak to?
```

2) If we ask a question about "Paul" (the subject), however, it will be a **subject question**, and then all we need to do is substitute the subject with a question word:

```
Who wants to speak to him?
```

Further reading with examples: in [this grammar book](http://books.google.ch/books?id=-C3qOp__YfYC&lpg=PA313&dq=%22subject%20questions%22%20grammar&pg=PA313#v=onepage&q&f=false)

3) It is possible to add an auxiliary verb in subject questions, that has already been discussed [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13469/auxilliary-do-with-the-subject-in-questions). To sum it up, it adds emphasis, as in:

```
A: Who wants to speak to him? Jack?
B: No.
A: Jim?
B: No.
A: Well, then who **does** want to speak to him?
```

More examples of that can be found in the link.

Comment: what about of :

1.can i change it ? vs do i can change it ? 
2. does it would change ? vs would it change?

What is the correct form?

Comment: @GilbertoIbarra The shortest answer I can give you: Modal verbs (can, would) do not take an auxiliary verb. They form the question themselves, just like 'to be'. So it is: "Can I change it?" and "Would it change?"